# How can I make PHP to access a given normal-user DRIVE without requesting OAUTH2 credentials?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-drive-api, flysystem-google-drive

I'm willing to manage a Google Drive folder via FlySystem. I've found tons of informations about accessing Google Drive via PHP thru the official client library.

But I find only 2 scenarios I can see and I need a 3rd one:

## Scenario a: Each user identifies himself

- If I use the OAUTH2 system, it is supposed that the user is prompted a login screen and thereafter the library can access their files (you need to configure the redirect URLs and so on).

## Scenario b: Access a "service account"

- If I use the service account, the program accesses the files of a "service account" that starts with an empty drive and does not have a user-friendly UI.

## Wanted scenario

- We currently have some standard user like `office-0004@my-nice-company.com` and that user is administered ONLY by the boss of the office.
- The boss uploads files that are available to the employees via the google-drive web interface. Currently `office-0004@my-nice-company.com` has a shared folder with all the employees.
- But we want to do some automation on file-uploading, but some other file uploading will still be manual.
- We don't want every employee to have access to the `office-0004@my-nice-company.com` credentials.
- I want PHP to manage that folder in `office-0004@my-nice-company.com`.

What I see:

- In scenario A, I should give employees the passwords of `office-0004@my-nice-company.com`
- In scenario B, I don't know how to make the boss access to -say- `google-drive-test@my-nice-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com` easily to see all the files via the standard drive web-UI.

## Question

- How can I make PHP to access files in a GIVEN REGULAR google account (not a service account), always the same account, wihout giving the users the password of that account?

PD: My final goal is use that drive from flysystem, although the question is not directly related to flysystem itself, but the drive access.

Comment: Contact the vendor of the cloud software product you want to use for your support options to clarify all of the access details. They can tell you, we can't.

Comment: 1) You can use a service account to access Google Drive. First, create a Drive Share and then add the service account identity (email) to the authorized list. Many StackOverflow answers show how to do this. 2) If your clients are Google Workspace users, then you can use Workspace Domain Wide Delegation to impersonate a user. 3) To answer your question, it not possible as you have no access to or any method of using a Google user's password. You must either use User OAuth or a service account.

Comment: As above - a service account can be created under the `office-0004@my-nice-company.com` account and used for automation without a user logging in, and can be given permission to the shared folder on the `office-0004@my-nice-company.com` Drive account, in the same way as human users.

Answer (score -1):

Found it.

## TL;DR

Long story short, it's **not** about having a service account. It's about using OAuth2 in "offline-mode".

## Use OAuth2, not a service account

This is the trick:

- In the normal OAuth2 flow, the user is in front of your application, requests access, then a screen pops up to authorize, and then the user gets redirected back to your application. A short-lived access-token is granted.
- In offline flow, you **manually** do once the popup process to authorize, but then you request a long-lived refresh-token, that the application will use to get your short-lived token in the background.

## Steps

Those are the steps to get the needed data.

1. Your create the application. Set a name. Get client_id and client_secret.
2. You configure the OAuth Screen. It's okey to have it in "development mode" (no need to publicly verify).
3. You create a set of credentials. Those will be of OAuth2 type.
4. Here you use the trick: Go to this client-simulator by google https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
5. There you can get the refresh-token.

Instructions found [here to get the client id and secret](https://github.com/ivanvermeyen/laravel-google-drive-demo/blob/master/README/1-getting-your-dlient-id-and-secret.md) and [here to get the reresh token](https://github.com/ivanvermeyen/laravel-google-drive-demo/blob/master/README/2-getting-your-refresh-token.md).

## Sample code

Here's my sample code using all that, tested and allowing access from one gmail account (containing the application) to go to another different, fixed-always-the-same account (containing the data).

In this example I create a standard cross-driver `League\Flysystem\Filesystem` object driven by a `Google\Client` configured in such a way that it accesses the files from a given specific google drive without user interaction (background/server use).

```
use Google\Client as GoogleClient;
use Google\Service\Drive;
use League\Flysystem\Config;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use League\Flysystem\Visibility;

// Define the class, etc. Next is a single method.
// Inject $this->googleClientConfig via configuration-injection.

private getGoogleDriveFilesystem() : Filesystem
{
    $config = [
        'client_id' => $this->googleClientConfig[ 'clientId' ],
        'client_secret' => $this->googleClientConfig[ 'clientSecret' ],
        'application_name' => 'My Nice App Sandbox FlySystem Test',
    ];

    // This consumes the standard PHP Google Client.
    $googleClient = new GoogleClient( $config );

    // This is the key to skip the user-interaction.
    $googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken( $this->googleClientConfig[ 'userRefreshToken' ] );

    $drive = new Drive( $googleClient );
    $adapter = new GoogleDriveAdapter(
        $drive,
        $this->googleClientConfig[ 'userRootFolder' ],
    );
    $filesystem = new Filesystem( $adapter, [ Config::OPTION_VISIBILITY => Visibility::PRIVATE ] );
    return $filesystem;
}
```

Comment: `Use OAuth2, not a service account`...these are not alternative options. OAuth2 is an authentication mechanism with various types of flows. When you use a service account, it still authenticates using OAuth2. Using a service account (and configuring it properly with the permissions it needs to access the Drive folder) would remove the need for a kludgy manual step to get a refresh token before you can use this code.

Comment: Offline line mode returns an OAuth refresh token. Refresh tokens expire and can be invalidated at any time. Your answer is only usable in a test and development scenario. You misunderstand how to authenticate and authorize using OAuth and what the tokens are for and how to manage them.

Comment: @ADyson it seemed to me that they were mutually exclusive options since when you create a credentials set, you are forced to choose one among those 3 options: [API key] or [OAuth client ID] or [Service account]. And for the service account the keys seem to be in a completely different format (a JSON you have to download, instead of a set of keys). What I meant is that choosing the [OAuth client ID] option is what worked for me.

Comment: @JohnHanley the expiration cases are documented here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration - Of course if I (myself) revoke the access to the application, the application won't access my files. Of course if I change the passwords, the application will be kicked out; if I change my passwords very probably is that I find there's a security risk and I want everything "out" from my files. I may cope with those. I am talking about an application for an office with workers, I may deal with "re-generating a refresh token if we change passwords".

Comment: Refresh tokens expire and can be revoked at any time. You can accept my comment or not. Your design is not correct and fixing that is up to you.

Comment: `you are forced to choose one among those 3 options: [API key] or [OAuth client ID] or [Service account]`...yes, but service account ultimately just uses a different OAuth flow to authenticate.  `choosing the [OAuth client ID] option is what worked for me`...but you wanted an automated scenario, and the first step of your process is a mnaual one. And as John says, the refresh token may not live forever. This is not a sustainable or reliable solution

Comment: Do some reading, please: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account